# CanvasJS: Making a chart dynamic with data.php, json encode and ajax(bandwidth meters)

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, canvasjs

First things first, I am trying to parse the data from a data.php file that uses json encode to echo a datapoint. The datapoint is updated every time the data.php file is requested, but not in a series of datapoints. Instead it just changes the time value and refreshes its y content. I haven't found a working way to actually make the php file echo series of datapoints and not update a single one.

Next up, the chart parses the data.php file and it indeed shows the datapoint. BUT I want to make this chart update every second and add new datapoints on every update so that I have a working bandwidth graph.

Here is my code:

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON("data.php", function (data_points) {
    var dps = data_points
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
zoomEnabled: true,
panEnabled: true,
animateEnabled: true,
data: [ {
type: "splineArea",
xValueType: "label",
y: "y",
dataPoints: dps } ]
});
chart.render();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**data.php:**

```
<?

session_start();
session_destroy();
session_start();

$rx[] = @file_get_contents("/sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/rx_bytes");
sleep(1);
$rx[] = @file_get_contents("/sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/rx_bytes");

$rbps = $rx[1] - $rx[0];

$round_rx=round($rbps/1, 2);

$time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$_SESSION['rx'] = $round_rx;
$data_points['label'] = $time;
$data_points['y'] = $_SESSION['rx'];

echo json_encode([$data_points]);

?>
```

If anyone know on how to make this map dynamic then please provide me some help.
An example output of the data.php file (what it echoes) is the following:

```
[{"label":"2015-09-12 21:34:12","y":1500}]
```

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update charts that way, you need to create chart only once (outside the ajax request) and keep adding new dataPoints via ajax request each second as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {

                    zoomEnabled: true,
                    panEnabled: true,
                    animateEnabled: true,
                    data: [ {
                        type: "splineArea",
                        xValueType: "label",
                        y: "y",
                        dataPoints: [] 
                    } ] 

                });

                function updateChart(){
                    $.getJSON("data.php", function (data_points) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < data_points.length; i++){
                            chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.push(data_points[i]);
                        }

                        chart.render();
                    });
                }               

                var updateInterval = 1000;

                setInterval(function(){
                        updateChart()
                }, updateInterval);

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh so I have to render the datapoints initially. Made some changes to reflect my code and worked. Thanks a million for the help.

Comment: can you please check my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401860/canvas-js-data-sampling-in-php) related to canvasjs?